# JSON key:value pairs disappearing after original json call

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have been trying to read data from JSON using Swift, but it hasn't been working after the original json call. Here is my code that does work:

```
func loadUrl(url:String){
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            let appUrl = URL(string:url)!
            let data = try Data(contentsOf:appUrl)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(json)
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Cannot connect to the server.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints this result:

```
["results": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60000000ae80>(
    {
        "address_components" =     (
                {
            "long_name" = Brooklyn;
            "short_name" = Brooklyn;
            types =             (
                political,
                sublocality,
                "sublocality_level_1"
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "New York";
            "short_name" = "New York";
            types =             (
                locality,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "Kings County";
            "short_name" = "Kings County";
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "New York";
            "short_name" = NY;
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "United States";
            "short_name" = US;
            types =             (
                country,
                political
            );
        }
    );
    "formatted_address" = "Brooklyn, NY, USA";
    geometry =     {
        bounds =         {
            northeast =             {
                lat = "40.739446";
                lng = "-73.83336509999999";
            };
            southwest =             {
                lat = "40.551042";
                lng = "-74.05663";
            };
        };
        location =         {
            lat = "40.6781784";
            lng = "-73.94415789999999";
        };
        "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
        viewport =         {
            northeast =             {
                lat = "40.739446";
                lng = "-73.83336509999999";
            };
            southwest =             {
                lat = "40.551042";
                lng = "-74.05663";
            };
        };
    };
    "place_id" = ChIJCSF8lBZEwokRhngABHRcdoI;
    types =     (
        political,
        sublocality,
        "sublocality_level_1"
    );
}
)
, "status": OK]
```

However, what I would like to do is go all the way to the formatted_address key. As soon as I try this code, however, the program crashes:

```
func loadUrl(url:String){
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            let appUrl = URL(string:url)!
            let data = try Data(contentsOf:appUrl)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
            let results = json["results"] as! [String:Any]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(results)
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Cannot connect to the server.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? The only thing that I have noticed is that the value of results is:

```
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x604000206d60>
```

I have no clue what this is. When I put the same json into an online viewer, the value was simply 0. Why is this? Shouldn't the value of "results" be address_components, formatted_address, geometry, place_id, and types?

Comment: What line crashes? What is the error?

Comment: 1. Never use `Data(contentsOf:)`, Use `URLSession` and a `dataTask`. 2. You really need to avoid all of those `!` operators. Safely cast. Safely unwrap. Code defensively.

Comment: And please do not post pictures of text. Copy and paste text as text, not pictures. It's easier to search, reference, read, and much easier to put in your question.

Comment: Line that crashes is let results = json[“results”] as! [String:Any]. The error is Tread 11: signal SIGABRT.

Comment: `results` is clearly an array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
if let results = json["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {

   if let first = results[0] as? [String:Any] {
          print(first["formatted_address"])
   }
}
```

Comment: Since `results` is clearly an array of dictionary, I suggest using `as? [[String:Any]]`.

Comment: Gives this error on the if let line:Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[Any]'

Comment: @rmaddy i do it inside the inner if , but since this improves readability i will edit

Comment: That doesn't cause the application to crash but formatted_address is never printed.

Comment: can you quickly print first and attach it

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: print the first variable in the answer and copy it from console

Comment: It printed Optional(Brooklyn, NY, USA)

Comment: I changed print(first["formatted_address"]) to print(first["formatted_address"]!), and it worked perfectly.